# Neural network options for simple data classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I want to clear about keras neural network options for classification of simple data where there are a number of features and one target column, as in *iris flower* dataset (Species is target):

```
SL,  SW,  PL,  PW,  Species
5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, setosa
4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, setosa
4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, setosa
...
...
```

I am finding that in almost all examples various combinations of `Dense` layers `Dropout` are the only options:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

What other keras layers can be used in such situations, especially if the data is large, say with 50K rows and 100 features?

Edit:  My specific question is whether Dense and Dropout are the only kind of layers for this purpose and such data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be very familiar with deep learning. Each kind of network is used for a special kind of task, you cannot just stack `LSTMs`, `GRUs`, dense layers and other stuff without supervision. If you have a task that your patterns are local and they may be in multiple locations in an input pattern, you can employ convolutional layers for feature extraction and you can employ dense layers for classifying those extracted features. If you want to classify data which there is a kind of sequence in it, temporal data, you can employ `LSTMs` and `GRUs` and you can stack them for better accuracy and you can use their output and feed them to other networks based on your need. `MLPs` are good for learning non-linear mappings.

Dropout is used for avoiding overfitting.

Comment: Very good brief description for many layers. By `"you can just stack LSTMs, GRUs, dense layers and other stuff without supervision"`, do you mean that these can be put in most situations and data?

Comment: I missed the **not**. You CANNOT!

Comment: Which particular layers can I add to my network for this data in my question above?

Comment: Increase the number of dense layers and employ dropout. Also increase the number of neurons in each layer.

Comment: By the way media, Can't these info be found very very easily by looking at the docs/examples associated at the repository? At least that's expected?

Comment: @Aditya ^^^^^^^^^^^________?????

Comment: Didn't get you, Like if someone is using Keras, then the docs are super clear and very well maintained to be cross referenced with the work at hand

Comment: My specific question is whether `Dense` and `Dropout` are the only kind of layers for this purpose and such data?

Comment: Let me not share your opinion. You are telling that due to being trained! For people out of the ecosystem, our jargons seem so odd and strange like the provided shape.

Comment: @rnso If you just want to classify, yes. If your data has some how a kind of positional dependancy, you can also employ `1D` convolutional layers for feature extraction and using dense layers after them. Consider that `dropout` is not a layer. It is a technique for ignoring neurons randomly in a layer.

Comment: Also checkout SpatialDropout if going for 1D Conv's..... In case of images nearby pixel's can still help to kind of simulate the original pixels that were zeroed out.. That's why the dropout

Comment: @Media : Thanks for a clear answer and for keeping beginners in mind.

Comment: Dropout -> Basically during training half of neurons on a particular layer will be deactivated. This improves generalization because it forces your layer to learn with different neurons the same "concept".

During the prediction phase the dropout is deactivated.... It's Basically a mask of 0's and 1's